Ubuntu 22.04: "Limited Connectivity"
I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.
A few days ago I started getting a "Limited Connectivity" error on Ubuntu and no access to the Internet. I did not change any network settings.
This happens both when I connect with cable or by Wi-Fi to my home router.
And now the interesting stuff: After I had setup a Wifi hotspot on my cell phone and connected to it, Ubuntu started to use the cable connection, at least judging from what UI was showing (!). But if I disconnect from the cell phone hotspot, I loose Internet connection completely.
There no problems with connection neither on Windows on the same PC nor mobile devices, so it must be something in Ubuntu.
I've recorded the attached gif while refreshing all tabs in a browser and you can see that the cable connection is used havily (~1MB/s) while the phone connection (Galaxy M51) is used very little (<1 kB/s). Yet if I disconnect from phone, I loose the connection from cable.


It was happening for three days, but now it suddenly fixed itself. I'll see if it breaks again tomorrow.

OK It happened again after restart, exact same thing. Connects by cable, but only if connected to a cell phone at the same time. Please let me know what commands should I run so you can diagnose it (I'm totally in blue in this topic)
